# How do I calculate the hamming distance in R on a set of binary values?

Tags: r, binary, hamming-distance

I need to compute the hamming distance and plot them in clusters in R for a dataset that has 2 columns and 45,000+ rows. Is there well known library available for this? Or do any strategies come recommended stronger than others?

I tried the hamming.distance function from the package "e1071", and get the error below. But even if I figure out how to calculate the hamming distance, I am not sure how to transition from those results to a cluster graph?

```
Error: evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion/options(expressions=)?
2015-02-02 18:50:59.704 R[1162:679616] Communications error:    <OS_xpc_error<error: 0x7fff7aaadb60> { count = 1, contents =
"XPCErrorDescription" => <string: 0x7fff7aaadfa8> { length = 22, contents =    "Connection interrupted" }
```

I tried this code:

```
 H<-hamming.distance(df)
```

Where df looks like this:

```
Name   Code
name1   0
name2   0
name3   1
name4   1
name5   0
```

Thank you for looking at this question and any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What clusters are you talking about? Do you use hclust or kmeans?

Answer (score 2):

To compare each row value to the previous row value, create a new column that is the previous row and apply this function across both columns.

```
df = data.frame(x1=as.character(c("0", "0", "1")))
df$x2 = c(NA, df$x1[-1])

hamming.distance = function(string1, string2){
  if (is.na(string2)==T) { 
    return (NULL)
  }
  string1 = as.character(string1)
  string2 = as.character(string2)

  length.string1 = nchar(string1)
  length.string2 = nchar(string2)

  if (length.string1 != length.string2) warning("Inputs must be of equal length")

 string.temp1 = c()
 for (i in 1:length.string1){
    string.temp1[i] = substr(string1, start=i, stop=i)
   }
  string.temp2 = c()
  for (i in 1:length.string2){
    string.temp2[i] = substr(string2, start=i, stop=i)
  }
   return(sum(string.temp1 != string.temp2))
}

results = mapply(hamming.distance, df[,1], df[,2])

unlist(results)
```

Note: the length of `unlist(results)` will be 1 shorter than the number of rows in your `df` object because the first entry is NA and `unlist` removes that value.

Comment: When I do apply(df,1,hamming.distance), I receive this error:
"Error in FUN(newX[, i], ...) : argument "string2" is missing, with no default". I have done some research for what this means, but am not coming up with very good results. Do you have any recommendations?

Comment: Are you comparing two column, for each row? Or are you comparing each row in your df to the preceding row?

Comment: I am comparing each row in the df to the preceding row.

Answer (score 1):

You can use stringdist package to calculate hamming distance: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stringdist/stringdist.pdf

For example:

```
library(stringdist)
df <- data.frame( column1 = c("toned", "10112"), column2 = c("roses", "10223"))
stringdistmatrix(df$column1, df$column2, method = c("hamming"))#for distance matrix
stringdist(df$column1, df$column2, method = c("hamming"))#for vector of distance
```

Comment: I typed install.packages(stringdist), and I get this error: Error in install.packages(stringdist) : object 'stringdist' not found. Also, when I type library(stringdist), I get this error: Error in library(stringdist) : there is no package called ‘stringdist’. Do you have any suggestions on what I may be doing wrong? Thank you.

Comment: Try install.packages("stringdist")